# Kendo grid show weird datetime instead of null

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

i format my datetime column like this:

```
{
    field: "ModifiedDate",
    dataType: "System.Date",
    title: accountCodeResourceProvider.ModifiedDate,
    format: "{0:G}",
    width: 150,
    hidden: true
}];
```

When it show up some empty value cell, instead of show blank field it's show "12/31/3938 5:00:00 PM". I tried a few template but none of them seem to work> Any body know how to handle this?

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"empty value cell"* here, but in my case(check demo below) it works fine with `null` or *empty* value.

Anyway, you can use a [`template`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template) to handle `null` dates:

```
template: "# if (data.ModifiedDate) { ##= kendo.toString(ModifiedDate, 'G') ## } else { #<em>No date</em># } #"
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/UBApOleM)